# Is it possible to model this padding with "inverted snake scale"-like pattern?

Tags: modeling

I`m new to Blender. There is a extruded square-like geometry on the surface of the headphones. As the geometry gets close to the boundaries, it changes shape. The shape changes from center to edges.

How do I make this effect?

[image: Snake-skin like mesh]

Comment: Look for tutorials about "Tissue" addon, it is shipped with Blender.

Comment: it looks amazing thx a lot :)

Answer (score 19):

Here is a different approach with a more non destructive workflow using modifiers.

[image]

Use a technique similar to Moonboots answer to start your shape.
Add a plane, subdivide-smooth a few times, poke faces, remove all orthogonal edges so you end up with the lozenges pattern.

Select all diagonal edges and with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> *Edges* menu mark them as *Sharp*.

Now poke you faces again, and select all face-center vertex. You can do this easily by selecting all *Sharp* edges from the above step with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> *Select Similar > Sharpness*, then switch to vertex mode and invert the selection.

Create a new vertex group and assign to it all the face center vertex selected previously, leaving all other out.

[image]

You can now add a new *Displace* modifier to your mesh and limit it to the above created vertex group. This will parametrically control the scales concavity with the displace amount.

Add an *Edge Split* modifier and tick only the option *Sharp Edges* to separate each individual scale. Follow it with a *Smooth* modifier to non destructively control the gap between scales.

Add a *Solidify* modifier to add thickness, then follow it by a *Subdivide* modifier set to *Simple*. This will add some gometry to "hold the square shape" of the scales.

After that you can add another *Subdivide* modifier set to *Catmull-Clark* to add roundness.

[image]

Comment: thank you a lot !!

Answer (score 15):

You could repeat a pattern with *Array* and *Curve* modifiers, but as Serge L says, a quick way would be to use the *Tissue* addon. The next *Tissue* addon made by Alessandro Zomparelli seems amazing by the way (Blendconf presentation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVNYyJeLGZI)):

Create a plane, subdivide it, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Un-Subdivide*, choose an *Iteration* value of 1 so that it creates lozenges instead of squares.

[image]

Create your module, make it rotate 45° on the Z axis. In *Object* mode select the module, then shift select the plane. In 2.79, in the *Tools* panel > *Create* tab > *Tissue*, press *Tessellate*, press *OK* to validate.

[image]

Comment: thx a lot guys i think im figuring it out hehe