How to model endothelium cells of an artery
How to model endothelium cells of an artery.  I am looking to achieve this offset brick pattern of the endothelium cells and have them displayed in a ring look.  Ultimately I am looking achieve the same look of the image.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/156614/is-it-possible-to-model-this-padding-with-inverted-snake-scale-like-pattern/

Is GeometryNodes a requirement ?

Create this pattern:

Array on 2 axis:

Use a Simple Deform modifier (Bend mode, 360° on Y with an empty as Object that is rotated 90° on Y), then the best is to bake the normals and use a normal map to fake the bumps:


Wow thank you for this! I and getting messed up at the simple deform section.  Please see edited post with updated image.

What does it give if you increase the Array count? Maybe share your file?

increasing the array count worked.  I don't know why I didn't try that.  Still new to blender.  Thank you so much!
